# I am trying to learn java asm framework for bytecode instrumentation but not able to find sufficient docs or tutorials on it

Tags: java, bytecode, instrumentation, java-bytecode-asm

I am trying to learn java asm framework for bytecode instrumentation but not able to find sufficient docs or tutorials on it.

I have studied about `ClassReader`, `ClassWriter` and `ClassVisitor` and some more alike APIs but not very clear about how to implement those and how to write corresponding adapters.

Lets say I have a HelloWorld java class.

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
//some code.....

    }

}
```

Now I want to insert a variable "int i =10;" in the bytecode. Please give me idea about what Adapter/program should I write.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/

Comment: Have you read: http://download.forge.objectweb.org/asm/asm4-guide.pdf ? There are simple examples there, I believe that explaining what you want to do (I read it some time ago so I'm not sure).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following is a way to add additional fields to a class such as "int i = 10;". 
Assuming that you are using javaagent to perform instrumentation:
1) Use the following as the premain class of the java agent

```
import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;

public class SimpleAgent {

    public static void premain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation inst) {

        ClassTransformer transformer = new ClassTransformer();
        inst.addTransformer(transformer);
    }
}
```

2) addTransformer calls the transform method of ClassTransformer class which is defined as follows

```
import java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer;
import java.lang.instrument.IllegalClassFormatException;
import java.security.ProtectionDomain;
import org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader;
import org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter;

public class ClassTransformer implements ClassFileTransformer{
    public byte[] transform(ClassLoader    loader,
            String              className,
            Class            classBeingRedefined,
            ProtectionDomain    protectionDomain,
            byte[]              b)
                    throws IllegalClassFormatException {
        try
        {
                ClassReader cr=new ClassReader(b);
                ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(cr,ClassWriter.COMPUTE_MAXS);
                AddField cp = new AddField(cw);
                cr.accept(cp,0);
                return cw.toByteArray();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return b;
    }
}
```

3) finally AddField which is as follows is the ClassVisitor that is responsible to add a new field to the class

```
import static org.objectweb.asm.Opcodes.ASM4;
import org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor;


class AddField extends ClassVisitor{

    static String className;
    static String methName, descrip;
    public AddField(ClassVisitor cv) {
        super(ASM4, cv);
    }

    @Override
    public void visit(int version, int access, String name,
            String signature, String superName, String[] interfaces) {
        className = name;
        cv.visit(version, access, name, signature, superName, interfaces);
    }
    public void visitEnd() {
        cv.visitField(0, "i", "I", null , new Integer(10));
        cv.visitEnd();
    }
}
```

4. ** NEW EDIT ** for adding a variable into a method. The variable has to be stored into a temporary variable and can then be used later. Following adapter can be used for the purpose (look at onMethodEnter):

```
import static org.objectweb.asm.Opcodes.ASM4;
import static org.objectweb.asm.Opcodes.*;
import org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor;
import org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor;
import org.objectweb.asm.commons.AdviceAdapter;

public class MethodAdapter extends ClassVisitor {


    public MethodAdapter(ClassVisitor cv) {
        super(ASM4, cv);
    }

    @Override
    public void visit(int version, int access, String name,
            String signature, String superName, String[] interfaces) {
        cv.visit(version, access, name, signature, superName, interfaces);
    }


    public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name,
            String desc, String signature, String[] exceptions) {
        MethodVisitor mv;
        mv = cv.visitMethod(access, name, desc, signature, exceptions);
        mv = new AddVariableAdapter(access, name, desc, mv);
        return mv;
    }
    public void visitEnd() {
        cv.visitEnd();
    }


    public class AddVariableAdapter extends AdviceAdapter{
        public AddCallAdapter(int access, String name, String desc,  
                MethodVisitor mv) {  
            super(ASM4, mv, access, name, desc);  
        }  

        protected void onMethodEnter()  {
            mv.visitIntInsn(BIPUSH, 10); // pushes the number 10 on to the stack
            mv.visitVarInsn(ISTORE, 1);  // pops the top of the stack into a local variable indexed by 1
        /*  code to print the local variable
            mv.visitFieldInsn(GETSTATIC, "java/lang/System", "out", "Ljava/io/PrintStream;");
            mv.visitVarInsn(ILOAD, 1);
            mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/io/PrintStream", "println", "(I)V");*/
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I think this is not the answer. He wanted to insert a variable, not a field.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I have added an adapter to add a variable.

Comment: How would you run this?

Answer (score 1):

A good way to find out how to use ASM is by running the [ASMifier](http://asm.ow2.org/asm40/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/util/ASMifier.html) tool. 
If you just want to know how certain language constructors such as variable initializers are converted to bytecode, it might be helpful to create a simple Java class, compile it, locate its `.class` file and run `javap` on it or open it with an IDE.